# find element in the middle of a stack

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, recursion

I was asked this question in an interview.The problem was i would be given a stack and have to find the element in the middle position of the stack."top" index is not available (so that you don't pop() top/2 times and return the answer).Assume that you will reach the bottom of the stack when pop() returns -1.Don't use any additional data structure.

Eg:

```
stack   index
----- 
 2    nth element
 3
 99
 .
 1    n/2 th element
 .
 -1   bottom of the stack(0th index)
```

Answer: 1 (I didn't mean the median.Find the element in middle position)

Is recursion the only way?

Thanks,

psy

Comment: "Find the element in middle position" -- that is definition of the median :) what you can use? no extra vars? what stack methods available, push, pop, others?

Comment: What the "middle" element of a stack with 4 elements? [ 4 13 22 31 ]? 13 or 22? ???

Comment: @Michael Foukarakis: ""top" index is not available"

Comment: @jancha No, median is the element with the middle *value*.

Comment: what I mean median key (index) obviously.

Comment: @kannan What do you mean by `"Is recursion the only way?"` Are you implying that you already know a solution?

Comment: BTW: I removed `stack` and added `algorithms` as I thought it would attract more attention.

Comment: Does the call stack count as a data structure? If not, then use recursion. But that is a convoluted and unsafe solution. Then again this is a pedantic interview question so all bets are off.

Comment: Isn't recursion equivalent to using another stack? The question says that additional data structures are not allowed. Does it mean "do not use other kinds of data structures (other than a stack)" or "do not use any other structures that can hold more than O(1) elements, including another stack"?

Comment: @quasiverse I know a solution for reversing the elements in a stack using recursion using only pops and pushes in a recursive way.I can use it to find the middle element.

Comment: @kannan - Even if one knows top of stack, Since top is just a pointer to a memory location and if stack grows downwards(actually which ever direction it grows), it is incorrect to say popping top/2 times would give 'middle element'. Pls correct if wrong.

Comment: @goldenmean i meant popping top's index/2 times... assume top element is at 100th index, so element at 50th index is middle element...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Walk through the stack, calculate the depth and on the way back return the appropriate element.

```
int middle(stack* s, int n, int* depth) {
  if (stack_empty(s)) {
    *depth = n;
    return 0; //return something, doesn't matter..
  }
  int val = stack_pop(s);
  int res = middle(s, n+1, depth);
  stack_push(s, val);
  if (n == *depth/2)
    return val;
  return res;
}

int depth;
middle(&stack, 0, &depth);
```

Note: yes, recursion is the only way. Not knowing the depth of the stack means you have to store those values somewhere.

Comment: +1 Iff OP clarifies that recursion is allowed. (And no, for those of you who didn't know, that wasn't a spelling mistake)

Comment: without additional data structure you *have to* use recursion to store those values somewhere.

Comment: recursion is allowed.I second your point.You have to use recursion to store the values. I thought there could be some other solution.

Answer (score 6):

Recursion is never the only way ;)

However, recursion provides you with an implied additional stack (i.e. function parameters and local variables), and it does appear that you need some additional storage to store traversed elements, in that case it appears that recursion may be the only way given that constraint.

Answer (score 1):

*"... Don't use any additional data structure. ..."*

Then the task is unsolvable, because you need some place where to store the popped-out data. You need another stack for recursion, which is also a data structure. It doesn't make sense to prohibit any data structure and allow recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution: Take two pointers, advance one of them two steps at a time (fast), the other one only one step at a time (slow). If the fast one reaches the bottom return the slow pointer which points to the middle index. No recursion required.

```
int * slow = stack;
int * fast = stack;
while(1) {
    if(STACK_BOTTOM(fast)) return slow;
    fast--;
    if(STACK_BOTTOM(fast)) return slow;
    slow--;
    fast--;
}
```

Comment: You do know what a stack is right? This assumes the stack is implemented in a certain way and that you have access to it's internals.

Comment: Does a stack define random access operations? If not, you will have to transfer everything you pop into a second stack, but the question specifically says not to use additional data structures.

Comment: True, but this is just to give one idea. If it's implemented with LinkedLists, one would have to adjust the code, but the principle would still work.

Comment: *facepalm* The point being made is that you *don't* know how the stack is implemented.

Comment: @rumpel, can you rewrite your code to use only "pop()" and "push()" operators? You assume that the data is still there for the "slow" pointer to access after you've seen it with the "fast" pointer, but I don't think that's possible with pop/push operations.

Comment: I agree, with only push() and pop() operations, this approach does not work.

Comment: @rumpel: If you have random access to the elements there's no point using 2 pointers. Just get a count of elements & divide by two.

Comment: @tenfour This is probably a solution for a linked list.

Comment: @rumpel:random access is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion seems to be the only way. If you try to use the fast and slow pointer concept during popping, you will need to store the values somewhere and that violates the requirement of no additional data structure.

Answer (score 0):

This question is tagged with `c`, so for the c programming language I agree that recursion is the only way. However, if first class anonymous functions are supported, you can solve it without recursion. Some pseudo code (using Haskell's lambda syntax):

```
n = 0
f = \x -> 0        # constant function that always returns 0

while (not stack_empty) do
    x = pop
    n = n+1
    f = \a -> if (a == n) then x else f(a)

middle = f(n/2)    # middle of stack

# stack is empty, rebuilt it up to middle if required 
for x in (n .. n/2) do push(f(x))
```

Please note: during the while loop, there's no (recursive) call of `f`. `f(a)` in the else branch is just used to construct a new(!) function, which is called `f` again.

Assumed the stack has 3 elements 10, 20, 30 (from bottom to top) this basically constructs the lambda

```
(\a -> if a==1
       then 30
       else (\b -> if b==2
                   then 20
                   else (\c -> if c==3
                                  then 10
                                  else (\d -> 0)(c)
                        )
                        (b)
            )
            (a)
)
```

or a little bit more readable

```
f(x) = if x==1 then 30 else (if x==2 then 20 else (if x==3 then 10 else 0))
```